# Magento 2 not working after attempted upgrade to 2.4.0

Tags: magento2, bug

I tried to upgrade magento from 2.3.5-p2 to 2.4.0 but I got an error in the frontend, so I changed back to 2.3.5-p2, deleted my whole `vendor` folder and executed `composer update` again.

But now my frontend does not work anymore and I get

```
There has been an error processing your request Class
Magento\Csp\Model\BlockCache does not exist
```

If I execute `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` then I get **There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.**

And if I execute `php bin/magento list` then I get:

> Magento CLI 2.3.5-p1
>
> Usage:   command [options] [arguments]
>
> Options:   -h, --help            Display this help message   -q,
> --quiet           Do not output any message   -V, --version         Display this application version
> --ansi            Force ANSI output
> --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output   -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question   -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the
> verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output
> and 3 for debug
>
> Available commands:   help  Displays help for a command   list  Lists
> commands
>
> In ServiceManager.php line 1129:
>
> An abstract factory could not create an instance of
> magentosetupconsolecommanddbstatuscommand(alias:
> Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DbStatusCommand).
>
> In ServiceManager.php line 940:
>
> An exception was raised while creating
> "Magento\Setup\Console\Command\DbStatusCommand"; no instance returned
>
> In ClassReader.php line 26:
>
> Class Vertex\Tax\Setup\Schema\Triggers\MigrateVertexInvoiceSent does
> not exist
>
> [company@company company.de]$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> There are no commands defined in the "setup" namespace.

So I deleted my `setup` folder and copied another one from a working magento 2 copy, but it still fails with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my PHP version via cPanel from 7.3 to 7.2 for the project and back to 7.3, then it worked suddenly. Not sure why.

Be careful, I think magento or the cPanel changed permissions of my magento folder and of the .htaccess file in the magento root. Check the permission there too!

I have set the permission of my project folder to 755 with `chmod 755 project-folder`

Comment: You should NOT use PHP 7.3.x. As official docs say ( https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#php ), Magento 2.4.0 is developed and tested on PHP 7.4.x. PHP 7.3.x should be only used in the upgrading process.

Comment: Yes, but I have bugs with PHP 7.4 and customers cant login anymore.